# Access Custom Tab Class Methods

Tags: java, javafx

My project includes a TabPane (detailsPane) that is populated with dynamically generated Tab objects. I have a custom class (DetailTab) that extends Tab to provide those tabs.

Within my DetailTab class, I include several methods that need to be access from my controller.

However, I am struggling to access the individual tabs themselves in order to call those methods.

So far, I've tried this in my controller:

```
private void buildComment() {
    StringBuilder comment = new StringBuilder();

    // Append comments from each tab
    for (Tab t : detailsPane.getTabs()) {
        t.getComment(comment);
    }
}
```

However, the getComment method is not accessible from the controller and I get the normal "Cannot resolve method" error.

The DetailTab class has the method:

```
public StringBuilder getComment(StringBuilder sb) {
    comment = sb;
    comment.append("Testing getComment()");
    return comment;
}
```

Could someone possibly tell me what I'm missing?  Running the following in my controller works just fine to get the title of the tab:

```
t.getText();
```

So it seems I'm accessing the correct DetailTab object; I just can't seem to get to the methods within it.

EDIT:
I have also tried a modified for loop to declare t as a DetailTab:

```
for (DetailTab t : detailsPane.getTabs()
```

The compile throws an Incompatible Type error for that:

```
Error:(205, 47) java: incompatible types: javafx.scene.control.Tab cannot be converted to DetailTab
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`TabPane.getTabs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html#getTabs--) returns `ObservableList<Tab>`. There is no `getComment` method in `Tab`; only the subclass `DetailTab` contains that method. Therefore you need to cast the `Tab` or the `List`:

```
for (Tab t : detailsPane.getTabs()) {
    ((DetailTab)t).getComment(comment);
}
```

or

```
for (DetailTab t : (List<DetailTab>) (List) detailsPane.getTabs()) {
    t.getComment(comment);
}
```

Both versions will result in a `ClassCastException` in case one of the `Tab`s is not a (sub)class of `DetailTab`.

---

Note that the type of the loop variable over a `Iterable<T>` (`List<T> extends Iterable<T>`) can only be a type assignable from `T` without a cast.